# Где и как защитить свой код?

Tags: php, авторские-права

Уважаемые профессионалы, подскажите пожалуйста, где и как защитить свой php код?

Я написал cms и не хочу, что бы её выдавали как свою.

Защитить имеется ввиду не закодировать, а именно дать понять, что код написанный мною и что я владелец.

Уже наступал на грабли, когда мою бесплатную систему тикетов продавали под чужими копирайтами.

Comment: Обычная практика в таких случаях, это расставлять везде копирайты с ссылкой на лицензию, под которой распространяется этот код. НО, это никак не защитит от выпила этих копирайтов или замена на свои. А после этого уже в суд.

Comment: выпускать под лицензией gnu gpl и не париться. Можно взглянуть? codereview провести.

Comment: @Naumov одна из самых ужасных лицензия.

Comment: codereview пока нет, потому что ещё не выпустил. На днях.

Comment: К стати есть IonCube лицензионный, может с помощью него сначала, что бы больше узнало о нём, а потом уже открывать код?

Comment: @Vartlok чем она так ужасна?

Answer (score 3):

Продать продукт - малая часть, дороже стоит его поддержка. Для усложнения до состояния фантастики поддержки можно сделать обфускацию кода. Хотя-бы тем-же ioncube.

Кражи неизбежны, и перепродажи тоже, но это может говорить о том, что ваш продукт нравится.

Есть безотказный способ защиты подобных проектов: пишется часть бизнес логики приложения, не требующая частого обновления, и выносится на свой сервер. Application клиента, установленный на сервере, при необходимости обращается на API вашего сервера, получает обработанный ответ и продолжает работать с уже обработанными данными. Но это реализовывали на платном продукте, знали кому продали, где стоял сервер и с какого IP с каким ключом будет приходить запрос на API.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю вам стоит воспользоваться Github и составить лицензию. И если это ваш код, то еще и запатентовать его. В таком случае вы можете подать в суд на продавцов вашей разработки.Да и советую сделать бекдор, который шлет отчеты о лицензии.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License

Comment: Как будто бы код, который шлёт отчёты, сложно точно так же выпилить. Кроме того, вряд ли люди станут доверять разработчику, в коде которого оставлен бекдор.

Comment: По крайней мере он сообщит, где лежит ваш продукт. Да и код порой сложно выпилить. Все зависит от вашего мастерства.

Comment: В версиях Windows 8, 8.1, 10 вообще кейлогер, который отсылает данные дядюшке Биллу. Так что код, который сообщает о том, на сервер установлена его CMS вообще мелочь. Для России стоит сделать, как Bitrix. Связка сервера на своей версии Linux и CMS. А для бесплатных лучший вариант github, свой сайт и анонс на хабре.

Comment: Он, по крайней мере, отключается и описан в документации. Так что то, что в Windows — не бекдор.

Comment: Про OWAS слышали? Не бекдор, так эксплоит. Знание своей системы тоже необходимо. А система лицензирования, которая сообщает вам о не лицензионной установке быть должна и точка. И решение сверху описано, привязать CMS к серверу. На данный момент это лучшая модель монетизации в России.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Zend Guard. Он кажется платный, но скорее всего он делает то, что вам как раз нужно.

Часто этой тулзой пользуются эксплойт-мейкеры. Они пишут сплойт, запаковывают скрипт Guard-ом и продают. Покупатель в итоге получает рабочий скрипт, пароль для его запуска и полностью не восстанавливаемый исходный код. У покупателя нет простой возможности разобраться как скрипт работает, и уж тем более его модифицировать. Запускать можно, менять нельзя (только через реверс-инжиниринг).